# Using panels instead of String in Autocompletetextfield

Tags: java, autocomplete, wicket, panels

I am using Wicket to build an ui for a searchengine on a website. As the user is typing the results are shown in a dropdown. As I have a lot of different objects (with each a different display structure) I want to define several panels. So for each found item in the db, it gets the right panel and right structure. So for example : if the searchengine finds a user, it should show only name. When a picture is found, a thumbnail and a description, etc...

Right now I am using the AutocompleteTextField but it only takes strings. I thought about adding html in the string and show it like that. But as that is not really a clean solution, I am thinking of using panels.

So, anyone know how I can use panels instead of the strings in a AutoCompleteTextField?

Comment: Further to the answers below, depending on the number and nature of the different things you want to display, you might want to use fragments instead of panels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own Component. Use a ListView, put it into a WebMarkupContainer. Show the WebMarkupContainer based on the TextField input and refresh the ListView in the OnChangeAjaxBehavior attached to the TextField.

This way you have full control over what you want to achieve.

Example code for the ListView:

```
   private ListView getLv(){
      ListView lv = new ListView(PANEL, new PropertyModel(this, "someList")) {
         @Override
         protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            Integer type = item.getModelObject().getType();
            if (type == 1) {
               item.add(new PanelType1("panel", item.getModelObject().someIdMaybe));
            } else if (type == 2) {
               item.add(new PanelType2("panel", item.getModelObject().someIdMaybe));
            }
         }
      };
      return lv;
   }
```

Comment: What kind of components can I show in the list? Ultimately I don't want to only use Labels as I will quickly reach the limit with that. Should I extend from the Component class and make my own or could I use a fragment?

Comment: Any Panel you want. I added some code to show how to populate the ListView.

Answer (score 3):

The `AutoCompleteTextField` uses the `newAutoCompleteBehavior`-hookmethod to create the behavior doing the display of the choices. This hookmethod takes an [IAutoCompleteRenderer](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/autocomplete/IAutoCompleteRenderer.html) as an argument. This renderer's actually doing the displaying part. So you could either pass your own renderer to the AutoCompleteTextField (there's a constructor accepting one) or subclass the `AutoCompleteTextField` to override the factory method. Either way you'll have to come up with your own implementation of `IAutoCompleteRenderer` since there is no such implementation in wicket and the renderer itself will be heavily influenced by your current application design.

Comment: Yes,thanks for the answer. I already thought of this but secretly hoped there was going to be a simpler way :p

Comment: @Merlijn The easiest solutions seems to be the one proposed by Robert Niestroj as the renderer would have to supply Strings to the Behavior...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to use panels, because a panel is a component, and itself could be anything. It will be too difficult to support any panel as a part of autocomplete list. It would be fun to have an autocomplete element as a form with autocomplete field;)

So, that's why there is `IAutoCompleteRenderer` interface to allow you generate any html markup for elements, but not as a panels.

As an option, maybe it is possible to have kind of modal pop up ajax dialog window using `ModalWindow`.