# Wicket: AutoCompleteTextField with "favourites"

Tags: java, wicket

I need to build an AutoCompleteTextField-like component where the user can mark some options as favourites (when he starts to write, some options show up and each option has a checkbox to mark it as favourite). The user can then check a checkbox outside the AutoCompleteTextField to choose whether only the favourites will be shown or on the contrary all the values no matter if they are favourites or not, will be all shown.

I have read [Using panels instead of String in Autocompletetextfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480544/using-panels-instead-of-string-in-autocompletetextfield) and i think it could be done using IAutoCompleteRenderer...

Any ideas?

Comment: Check https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/jdk-1.7-parent/objectautocomplete-parent. It may be in help.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the solution provided by Robert in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15484348/461499.

Why?

If you have complete control over how the choices are rendered (by using plain Wicket Components instead of javscript), you can built a very rich component. Although I think it will take some extra javascript effort to make the choices-panel look and feel correct, it should be worth the investment.